# Vis.js not showing graph when many nodes are added

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am making a web app to show relationships between items using `Vis.js`, everything works perfectly fine until I get to the point where I need to display ~260 nodes with ~1200 edges between them.

Once I get to that amount of nodes, the graph just shows a blank space and a blue line, nothing else. As soon as I try to zoom it, the line disappears and it's all white.

When I look at the position of the nodes I can see that many of them are in negative or very big `x, y` positions (generally -300 for x and around 478759527705558300000 for y).

I have tried, to no avail, to disable physics. The graph is in hierarchichal mode, with levels manually set in the code, but the levels are correct.

Network options (the `improvedLayout` option was just a possibility I found on the internet; it works just the same if I remove it):

```
    var options = {
        layout: {
            improvedLayout: false,
            hierarchical: {
                direction: direction,
                sortMethod: "directed"
            }
        }
    }
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you letting vis.js manage the layout and just providing the arrays of nodes and edges? Where did the x, y coordinate data come from?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I am letting vis.js manage the layout since it is hierarchical, I am providing the nodes (each one with a `level`argument). It works fine with smaller sets of data

Comment: You might try using `network.fit();` after the layout is complete to see if you have an issue with the zoom.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I tried to do it, but nothing changes. Still the same line.

Comment: Perhaps update your question with the `options` you are passing to e.g `new vis.Network(container, data, options);`...

Comment: Just added them @RobinMackenzie
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have hierarchical layout graph which consists of around 615 nodes and 614 edges (excluding 40 odd cluster nodes, some of them cluster of clusters). I landed into same problem with visjs.

One quick thing which helped me to get over this problem was to explicitly  call [network](http://visjs.org/docs/network/).stabilize() method with an argument specifying number of iterations. Default iterations are 1000. I passed 10000 and graph stabilized it self nicely. It took a few more seconds, i was fine with that. But stabilization times shoots up as number nodes increased to ~1000. So i started looking into visjs code for solution.

While looking in visjs code, i found that inside function setupHierarchicalLayout() there is a call to [_condenseHierarchy()](https://github.com/almende/vis/blob/master/lib/network/modules/LayoutEngine.js#L365). 
This method tries to minimize white spaces between nodes and edges (***yet to understand the code fully***). _condenseHierarchy() modifies coordinates of a node. See Y coordinate before and after call to _condenseHierarchy() below:

```
(this.body.nodes["node-11"]).y
1530
(this.body.nodes["node-11"]).y
64920
```

When a node gets a distant position it takes lots of iterations (in stabilize) to bring it closer together with other nodes in graph. I disabled _condenseHierarchy() and got the graph displayed nicely.

I'm sure disabling _condenseHierarchy() would bring in some other issues as i proceed further. I am going to spend some more time to understand and experiment with _condenseHierarchy().

Comment: Interesting insight into how the library works inside. We eventually (time constraints) had to leave this fix in the "backlog", so we did not find any real solution. However, if there is time in the future to investigate your solution, I will post the outcome. Thanks!

Edit: Selecting as answer since it provides a workaround

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can adjust hierarchical layout parameters, such as nodeSpacing, levelSeparation and treeSpacing. Here is an example [hierarchicalLayoutWithoutPhysics](http://visjs.org/examples/network/layout/hierarchicalLayoutWithoutPhysics.html)

Comment: Please don't post "me too" as an answer. Instead, you may star this question as a favorite to be notified of any new answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, [you may also upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it, or [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to attract more attention.